# Python Celery: 2-way communication between worker and task requester

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to achieve 2 way communication between the worker and the task requester, once the task has been scheduled. So far I was only able to achieve one-way communication (worker -> requester):

```py
@app.task(bind=True)
def long_task(self: celery.Task):
    time.sleep(1)
    self.update_state(state="PROGRESS", meta={"progress": 50})
    time.sleep(1)
    self.update_state(state="PROGRESS", meta={"progress": 90})
    time.sleep(1)
    self.update_state(state="DONE", meta={"progress": 100})
    return "done"


result: celery.result.AsyncResult = long_task.apply_async()
result.get(on_message=on_message) # on_message callback will receive progress updates.
```

Is it possible to also send the additional information to the worker **after** `long_task.apply_async()` call?

Unfortunately, some information needed for task completion is only available slightly later. I could create a separate connection by sending the IP of the "task requester", but this is a bit painful. If there exists some 2 way connection already I would prefer to reuse it.